# How to do opposite of explode in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a `DataFrame` with a column for users and another column for words they've written:

```python
Row(user='Bob', word='hello')
Row(user='Bob', word='world')
Row(user='Mary', word='Have')
Row(user='Mary', word='a')
Row(user='Mary', word='nice')
Row(user='Mary', word='day')
```

I would like to aggregate the `word` column into a vector:

```python
Row(user='Bob', words=['hello','world'])
Row(user='Mary', words=['Have','a','nice','day'])
```

It seems I can't use any of Sparks grouping functions because they expect a subsequent aggregation step. My use case is that I want to feed these data into `Word2Vec` not use other Spark aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the spark 2.3 release we now have Pandas UDF(aka Vectorized UDF).  The function below will accomplish the OP's task...  A benefit of using this function is the order is guaranteed to be preserved.  Order is essential in many cases such as time series analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
import findspark

findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test_collect_array_grouped').getOrCreate()

def collect_array_grouped(df, groupbyCols, aggregateCol, outputCol):
    """
    Aggregate function: returns a new :class:`DataFrame` such that for a given column, aggregateCol,
    in a DataFrame, df, collect into an array the elements for each grouping defined by the groupbyCols list.
    The new DataFrame will have, for each row, the grouping columns and an array of the grouped
    values from aggregateCol in the outputCol.

    :param groupbyCols: list of columns to group by.
            Each element should be a column name (string) or an expression (:class:`Column`).
    :param aggregateCol: the column name of the column of values to aggregate into an array
            for each grouping.
    :param outputCol: the column name of the column to output the aggregeted array to.
    """
    groupbyCols = [] if groupbyCols is None else groupbyCols
    df = df.select(groupbyCols + [aggregateCol])
    schema = df.select(groupbyCols).schema
    aggSchema = df.select(aggregateCol).schema
    arrayField = StructField(name=outputCol, dataType=ArrayType(aggSchema[0].dataType, False))
    schema = schema.add(arrayField)
    @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def _get_array(pd_df):
        vals = pd_df[groupbyCols].iloc[0].tolist()
        vals.append(pd_df[aggregateCol].values)
        return pd.DataFrame([vals])
    return df.groupby(groupbyCols).apply(_get_array)

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(user='Bob', word='hello'),
                                      Row(user='Bob', word='world'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='Have'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='a'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='nice'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='day')])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

collect_array_grouped(df, ['user'], 'word', 'users_words').show()

+----+--------------------+
|user|         users_words|
+----+--------------------+
|Mary|[Have, a, nice, day]|
| Bob|      [hello, world]|
+----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 47):

Thanks to @titipat for giving the RDD solution. I did realize shortly after my post that there *is* actually a DataFrame solution using `collect_set` (or `collect_list`):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(user='Bob', word='hello'),
                                      Row(user='Bob', word='world'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='Have'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='a'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='nice'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='day')])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
group_user = df.groupBy('user').agg(collect_set('word').alias('words'))
print(group_user.collect())

>[Row(user='Mary', words=['Have', 'nice', 'day', 'a']), Row(user='Bob', words=['world', 'hello'])]
```

Comment: Nice solution Evan! I was going to post the pyspark dataframe solution too but you figured already :)

Comment: Is order preserved with collect_list?

Comment: @Evan I do know doing oderby with collet_list does not preserve order.

Comment: @Evan it is a different situation. The orderby order is not respected. I know that because it bit me, but I never could figure out if collet_list preserves the original order. What happens if the list is from data that spans partitions?  The behavior is not well documented.

Comment: In my case with bag of words order didn’t matter, but I’m sure it could matter in some applications. I guess as a rule I wouldn’t assume order is preserved unless the docs explicitly say.

Comment: I am working with time series data and it seems like collect_list is preserving the order correctly

Answer (score 22):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupby("user").agg(F.collect_list("word"))
```

Comment: @lfvv collect_set removes duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using `rdd`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(user='Bob', word='hello'),
                                      Row(user='Bob', word='world'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='Have'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='a'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='nice'),
                                      Row(user='Mary', word='day')])
group_user = rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x.user)
group_agg = group_user.map(lambda x: Row(**{'user': x[0], 'word': [t.word for t in x[1]]}))
```

**Output** from `group_agg.collect()`:

```
[Row(user='Bob', word=['hello', 'world']),
Row(user='Mary', word=['Have', 'a', 'nice', 'day'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a native aggregate function for that, collect_set (docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set)).

Then, you could use:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupby("user").agg(F.collect_set("word"))
```