# Create a nested data after join in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

My goal is to prepare in spark/Hadoop a dataframe that i will index it in elasticsearch .

I have 2 orc table : `client` and `person` . The relation is one-to-many

1 client can have multiple person .

So i will be using Spark/Spark SQL , so lets speak dataframe :

The client dataframe schema :

```
root 
|-- client_id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c2: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c3: string (nullable = true)
```

The person dataframe schema :

```
root 
|-- person_id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- p1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- p2: string (nullable = true) 
|-- p3: string (nullable = true) 
|-- client_id: string (nullable = true)
```

My goal is to generate a Dataframe that will have this schema :

```
root 
|-- client_id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c2: string (nullable = true) 
|-- c3: string (nullable = true) 
|-- persons: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | |-- person_id: string (nullable = true) 
| | |-- p1: string (nullable = true) 
| | |-- p2: string (nullable = true) 
| | |-- p3: string (nullable = true)
```

How i can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: join and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357727/how-to-do-opposite-of-explode-in-pyspark?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group` the `person` dataframe by `client_id` and create a `list` of all other `columns` and `join` with the `client` dataframe as below

```
//client data 
val client = Seq(
  ("1", "a", "b", "c"),
  ("2", "a", "b", "c"),
  ("3", "a", "b", "c")
).toDF("client_id", "c1", "c2", "c2")

//person data 
val person = Seq(
  ("p1", "a", "b", "c", "1"),
  ("p2", "a", "b", "c", "1"),
  ("p1", "a", "b", "c", "2")
).toDF("person_id", "p1", "p2", "p3", "client_id")

//Group the person data by client_id and create a list of remaining columns 
val groupedPerson = person.groupBy("client_id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("person_id", "p1", "p2", "p3")).as("persons"))


//Join the client and groupedPerson Data 
val resultDF = client.join(groupedPerson, Seq("client_id"), "left")

resultDF.show(false)
```

**Schema:**

```
root
 |-- client_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- persons: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- person_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- p1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- p2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- p3: string (nullable = true)
```

**Output:**

```
+---------+---+---+---+------------------------+
|client_id|c1 |c2 |c2 |persons                 |
+---------+---+---+---+------------------------+
|1        |a  |b  |c  |[[p1,a,b,c], [p2,a,b,c]]|
|2        |a  |b  |c  |[[p1,a,b,c]]            |
|3        |a  |b  |c  |null                    |
+---------+---+---+---+------------------------+
```

Hope this helps !