# Spark SQL - Group and String Aggregate

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Sorry but I'm new in spark sql.

How do I convert a dataframe from As-Is to To-Be as follows?

**As-Is**

[image]

**To-Be**

[image]

Basically, it's to group certain columns and string aggregate the selected column in this case.

Comment: You can use what is already mentioned in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357727/how-to-do-opposite-of-explode-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `concat_ws` and the aggregation function `collect_list`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupby(
    'Col 1','Col 2'
).agg(
    F.concat_ws(",", F.collect_list('Col 3')).alias('Col 3')
)

+-----+-----+-----+
|Col 1|Col 2|Col 3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|Item1|    1|  a,b|
|Item1|    2|    c|
|Item2|    3|    d|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one -

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(Col1='Item1', Col2=1, Col3='a'),
    Row(Col1='Item1', Col2=1, Col3='b'),
    Row(Col1='Item1', Col2=2, Col3='c'),
    Row(Col1='Item2', Col2=3, Col3='d'),
])

result_df = df \
    .groupBy('Col1', 'Col2') \
    .agg(collect_list('Col3').alias('Col3')) \
    .withColumn("Col3", concat_ws(",", "Col3"))

display(result_df)
```